# How does Canonical report and transfer Software Center sales money to app developers?

Tags: software-center, application-development, canonical, paid-applications

I would like to clarify some details of the derivation earned from the sale of application money. If I understood correctly, at the end of each quarter you will send us email to report the amount of earned us money. After that we will send you requisites on which you will send money by bank transfer. Am I right?

Answer (score 5):

To clarify - Canonical will send a report within 30 days after the end of each quarter. Canonical will also send payment within 30 days after the end of each quarter (usually simultaneously - unless payment questions arise).

The TOS (click through agreement) states that Canonical will send a report, the developer will return a invoice, and Canonical will pay that invoice. This is the procedure, however Canonical has streamlined the process to what is stated above (send report, send payment immediately thereafter).

If a payment or report issue arises, you can reply to the report sender or contact me directly for resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Citet from the [Commercial Software FAQ](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/):

> Payment
>
> How do I get paid for the sales of my application?
>   Currently, we pay all publishers on a quarterly basis. 
>   Following publishing of your application we’ll contact you for confirmation of
>   your invoice details. We’ll then pay you electronically, via bank
>   transfer for PayPal, each quarter. In the future we’ll introduce
>   monthly automated payment.
>
> How will I receive my money?
>
> You’ll receive an invoice and your payments on a quarterly basis. 
>   We pay the publisher either by electronic bank transfer or through
>   PayPal. For Paypal payments we’ll pay the registered address that’s
>   associated with your account in the Developer Portal.

So it seems to me that you will give the payment details directly following the publishing of the software. It does not seem like you give the details after each quarter report.

If you need more and official information, you might want to ask Canonical directly.